# Javascript function does not execute, script continues normally

Tags: javascript, function

It's been a long night trying to solve this one.

I'm trying to load a small text file, parse it, then use the information to provide the user with video options. I do this when the page loads but I also do it in response to a user event. In both cases I get the same result. The load_playList function does not execute.

The code is below. The window.load and selectVideo(X) routines are the starting points. In both cases the load_Playlist function is ignored.

It seems that load_playList never executes. The alert message is never executed, yet the script continues as if everything were normal. It's as if I typed the  function's name wrong, so I did that and the script failed. So, the browser seems to see the function, but ignores it.

```
var videoList = [];
var videoTitles = [];
var videoCaptions = [];

/*
var videoList = [
    'videos/ZionParkParade.mp4', 
    'videos/Pointless2014.mp4'];
var videoTitles = [
    'The 50GT Zion Canyon Cruise',
    'The Tinyvette at Sonoma Raceway'];
var videoCaptions = ['Caption 1','Caption 2'];
*/

window.onload = function()
{
    alert(0);
    load_playList;      // Loads and parses a small text file.
    alert(1);
    load_video(0);      // Set up the first video to play.
    alert(2);
}

function load_playList()
{
    alert('load_playList');
    var listFile = ReadFile('videos/PlayList.txt');

    var playList = listFile.split('\n');

    var j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < math.trunc(playList.length / 3); i++) 
    {
        videoList[i] = playList[j];
        videoTitles[i] = playList[j+1];
        videoCaptions[i] = playList[j+2];
        j++;
        j++;
        j++
    }
}

function selectVideo(X)
{
    alert(10);
    load_playList;      // Loads and parses a small text file.
    alert(11);
    load_video(Number(X));
    alert(12);
}

function FileRead(U) 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        X=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        X=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  X.open('GET', U, false );
  X.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  X.send();
    return X.responseText;
}   

function load_video(N)
{
    var V = document.getElementById("video_player");
    V.pause();
    V.src = videoList[N];
    V.auto = false;
    V.type = "video/mp4";

    // Update the title and captions.
  document.getElementById('pause_button').innerHTML = "Play";
    document.getElementById('videoTitle').innerHTML = videoTitles[N];
    document.getElementById('videoCaption').innerHTML = videoCaptions[N];
}
```

If I un-comment the initial variable declarations, o provide initial values, everything works, except the text file is never loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Edit - I found two problems in the load_playList routine but still can't get that function to run. I don't even see the first alert.

I pasted the load_playList code into the onload routine and it works. I can live with that, but danged if it makes any sense.

```
window.onload = function()
{
//  load_playList;      // Loads and parses a small text file.

    var listFile = load_file('videos/PlayList.txt');
    var playList = listFile.split('\n');

    var j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < Math.trunc(playList.length / 3); i++) 
    {
        videoList[i] = playList[j];
        videoTitles[i] = playList[j+1];
        videoCaptions[i] = playList[j+2];
        j++;
        j++;
        j++
    }

    load_video(0);      // Set up the first video to play.
    var vid = document.getElementById("video_player");
    vid.volume = 0.2;   
}

function load_playList()
{
alert(10);
    var listFile = load_file('videos/PlayList.txt');
alert(11);
    var playList = listFile.split('\n');

alert('Length = '+playList.length); 
alert('Count = '+Math.trunc(playList.length / 3));  

    var j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < Math.trunc(playList.length / 3); i++) 
    {
        videoList[i] = playList[j];
        videoTitles[i] = playList[j+1];
        videoCaptions[i] = playList[j+2];
        j++;
        j++;
        j++
    }
alert(12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include `()` after the function name. Just calling the name won't run the function.

```
load_playList();
```

[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions)
Also refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfz89Lsn/1/) for watching a function call

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tired that. It crashes the script.

Comment: When I include the () I get the alert for 0, but none of the others. Without the () I get all three alerts, but the load_playList function never executes.

window.onload = function()
{
alert(0); 
 load_playList();  // Loads and parses a small text file.
alert(1); 
 load_video(0);  // Set up the first video to play.
alert(2); 
 var vid = document.getElementById("video_player");
 vid.volume = 0.2;  
}

Comment: There might be some error in that function then. Because just you get other functions to work doesn't mean you will change the fundamentals of how functions are called

Answer (score 0):

The work-around, pasting that routine's code into the onload routine, worked, but I wasn't satisfied and finally stumbled on this as a solution:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    load_playList(0);       // Loads and parses a small text file.
    load_dropdown(0);       // Populate the dropdown menu.
    load_video(0);          // Set up the first video to play.
    var vid = document.getElementById("video_player");
    vid.volume = 0.2;   
}
```

Neither load_playList nor load_dropdown need an argument passed to them but I did anyway, and that worked.

I'm not sure why this is so but I'll take it.